# Multiple bean detection with GroupedOpenApi

Tags: springdoc, spring-boot-3

After migration from spring-boot `3.0.5` to `3.2.3`, I get this error:

```
Parameter 0 of method usersGroup in xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.config.apidoc.OpenAPIConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - openApiCustomizer: defined by method 'openApiCustomizer' in class path resource [xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/config/apidoc/OpenAPIConfiguration.class]
    - actuatorOpenApiCustomizer: defined by method 'actuatorOpenApiCustomizer' in class path resource [org/springdoc/core/configuration/SpringDocConfiguration$SpringDocActuatorConfiguration.class]
```

I already defined a custom springdoc config like this:

```
@Configuration
public class OpenAPIConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public OpenApiCustomizer openApiCustomizer () {
                return new CustomOpenApiCustomizer();
        }

        @Bean
        public GroupedOpenApi usersGroup(OpenApiCustomizer openApiCustomizer) {
                return GroupedOpenApi.builder().group("group-name")
                        .addOpenApiCustomizer(openApiCustomizer)
                        .build();
        }
}
```

The solution is just to exclude `SpringDocActuatorConfiguration` ?